# Передать значение с php функции обработчика ajax запроса, другой функции внутри function.php до отправки ответа?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Как сохранить или передать значение с php функции обработчика в момент срабатывания ajax запроса на сервер, другой функции внутри function.php до момента отправки ответа ?

Пробывал через global, передать параметром в другую функцию, просто записать в файл на сервере, но так не работает. Сам ajax в паре с функцией отрабатывает нормально, но как в момент срабатывания php функции на сервере поймать и передать то что пришло с ajax дальше, не могу понять, это вообще возможно перехватывать эти данные?

AJAX запрос на сервер:

```
 $(".submit-button").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if($("#one__q1").attr("checked") == 'checked') {
        var answer11 = $("#one__q1").val();
    }
    if($("#one__q2").attr("checked") == 'checked') {
        var answer12 = $("#one__q2").val();
    }
    if($("#one__q3").attr("checked") == 'checked') {
        var answer13 = $("#one__q3").val();
    }
  //  var answer11 = $("#one__q1").val();
   // var answer12 = $("#one__q2").val();
  //  var answer13 = $("#one__q2").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            action: 'ajax_order',
            answer11: answer11,
            answer12: answer12,
            answer13: answer13

        },
        success: function (response) {
            $('.resp').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Функция обработчик на сервере, собственно с которой я хочу взять данные полученные от ajax до момента отправки ответа (не важно в каком виде,массив, строка тд):

```
function ajax_form(){
    $answer11 = $_POST['answer11'];  
    $answer12 = $_POST['answer12'];
    $answer13 = $_POST['answer13'];
    $response1 =  $answer11 . $answer12 . $answer13;   // как сохранить или передать это значение другой функции в файле function.php ? 

    if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){
        echo $response1;  // собственно все ок, ответ от сервера уходит
        wp_die();
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_order', 'ajax_form' );
```

Хотел данные которые приходят в файл записать(он есть на сервер), но запрос отрабатывает а файл пустой

```
function ajax_form(){
$answer11 = $_POST['answer11'];
$answer12 = $_POST['answer12'];
$answer13 = $_POST['answer13'];
$response1 =  $answer11 . $answer12 . $answer13;

$fp = fopen("one_q.txt", "r+"); 
fwrite($fp, $response1);
fclose($fp);// Запись в файл

if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ){
    echo $response1;  // собственно все ок, ответ от сервера уходит
    wp_die();
}
```

}

Comment: Почему бы просто не передать значение в качестве параметра функции? Что-то вроде `your_function($response1);`

Comment: Вам надо вызвать из `ajax_form()` вашу функцию. Не понимаю, чего вы хотите.

Comment: Не вызвать функцию, а взять данные с $_POST которые приходят от AJAX

Comment: "Почему бы просто не передать значение в качестве параметра функции? Что-то вроде your_function($response1);" - не работает так, я пробывал

Comment: @alexei, так вы принимайте эти параметры в вашей функции и всё будет работать.

Comment: " так вы принимайте эти параметры в вашей функции и всё будет работать" - можно пожалуйста точнее, где принимать, ведь я их принимаю $answer11 = $_POST['answer11'];

Comment: В той функции, которую вы хотите вызвать.

Comment: function my_tesat_s($response1){
    
    return $response1;
}

Comment: вы это имеете в виду?

Comment: Именно. Только в таком виде функция не имеет смысла

Comment: function my_tesat_s($response1){

    echo $response1;
}

Comment: так имеет смысл?

Comment: Я не буду обсуждать с вами каждую строчку вашего кода, тем более не видя всей картины. Отредактируйте вопрос, максимально понятно изложив в нём то, чего же вы всё-таки хотите добиться.

Comment: Я для примера, спасибо что пытались помочь, все эти варианты я пробовал раньше, думал может что то упустил

Comment: @alexei, видимо, что-то упустили, так как вариант, описанный мной в первом комментарии, вполне успешно работает.